# Magento 2 generate product data based on cron job

Tags: magento2, cron, products

I am developing an admin module which has the functionality to generate product csv in format XML, CSV and txt. I am inserting a row for each format in the database. So when we click on generate button(which is in admin header) it fetches the details(filename,type,cronschedule...) from the database for particular id.Now I want to schedule automatically generate the files(xml,csv,txt) and each row has settings of cron job(which are stored in a custom table).

I have no idea how to set the cron job of each row so that it generates data automatically based on cron settings in rows.

If anyone has an idea. Please let me know with all steps.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more about your required functionality and what you have accomplished so far?

Comment: Can you provide the screenshot of it, which is currently working?